# Find most duplicated numbers inside a array

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

I have the following array

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2]`
```

I want to find out 2 things:

1) How many duplicates of each number is it?

For instance: **1, 3 times**, **4, 2 times** etc.

2) Find 3 most duplicated numbers in the `array`.

For instance: `[2, 3, 1]` since **2** is duplicated **5 times**, **3** is duplicated **4 times** & **1** is duplicated **3 times**.

I have tried

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2]
= arr.group_by { |e| e }.map { |e| e[0] if e[1][1] }.compact
```

But results are not what I am looking for: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:ruby-on-rails], tag removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a count of duplicated entries per duplicate you can go with:

```
arr.group_by(&:itself)
   .each_with_object({}) {|(k, v), hash| hash[k] = v.size }
#=> {1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>4, 4=>2, 5=>2}
```

To get 3 most duplicated entries:

```
arr.group_by(&:itself)
   .sort_by { |_k, v| -v.size }
   .take(3)
   .map(&:first)
#=> [2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
▶ arr.group_by { |e| e } # arr.group_by(&:itself) for Ruby >= 2.2
     .map { |k, v| [k, v.count] } #⇒ [[1, 3], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 2], [5, 2]]
     .sort_by { |(_, cnt)| -cnt } #⇒ [[2, 5], [3, 4], [1, 3], [4, 2], [5, 2]]
     .take(3)                     #⇒ [[2, 5], [3, 4], [1, 3]]
     .map(&:first)
#⇒ [2, 3, 1]
```

Remove three last clauses to get the whole unsorted result.

Comment: Thanks @mudasobwa :)

Answer (score 0):

1) How many duplicates of each number is it?

```
counts = Hash[arr.uniq.map{|_x| [_x, arr.count(_x)]}]
=> {1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>4, 4=>2, 5=>2}
```

2) Find 3 most duplicated numbers in the array

```
counts.sort_by { |a, b| -b }.take(3).map(&:first)
=> [2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2]
```

I suggest using a counting hash (see the reference to "default value" at [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new)):

```
h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
  # => {1=>3, 2=>5, 3=>4, 4=>2, 5=>2}
```

and use the method [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) with an argument of `3` to obtain the three keys of `h` having the largest values:

```
h.max_by(3, &:last).map(&:first)
  #=> [2, 3, 1]
```

Note that if `h` is largish, using `max_by` with an argument is more efficient that using [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) or [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) and then discarding all but the three largest values. The `Enumerable` methods `max_by`, `min_by` `max` and `min` were changed to permit an argument (which defaults to `1`) in Ruby v2.2.